# Mixed Integer Linear Programming to And/Or Constraints

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I'm looking to satisfy a set of constraints using PuLP and I'm not exactly sure how to set up the variables to do so.

For example, how would I set up variables for the following constraint:

`((x_1 < x_2) AND (x_1 < x_3)) OR ((x_1 > x_2) AND (x_1 > x_3))`

A variable x_1 is either less or greater than both, x_2 and x_3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) including error messages, you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint

```
 ((x1 <= x2) AND (x1 <= x3)) OR ((x1 >= x2) AND (x1 >= x3))
```

can be formulated with just one extra binary variable:

```
 x1 <= x2 + delta*M
 x1 <= x3 + delta*M
 x1 >= x2 - (1-delta)*M
 x1 >= x3 - (1-delta)*M
 delta in {0,1}
```

Most advanced solvers have indicator constraints, allowing us to write this without big-M's:

```
 delta = 0 -> x1 <= x2
 delta = 0 -> x1 <= x3
 delta = 1 -> x1 >= x2
 delta = 1 -> x1 >= x3
 delta in {0,1}
```

Comment: I had to read through and implement the other answer first before I could understand this simplified answer. This is clean and helps a lot. Thank you! Even though LP doesn't generally handle inequalities I'm guessing this can be correct with some small constant value c? For example:

x1 + c<= x2 + delta M;
 x1 + c<= x3 + delta M;
 x1 >= c + x2 - (1-delta)M;
 x1 >= c + x3 - (1-delta)M;
 delta in {0,1}

Answer (score 3):

First a remark: there is no `<` operator in Linear-programming. There is only `<=`. This means: if you want strict inequalities, you will need to add some small constant *epsilon*!

Now let's assume your task looks like: `((x1<=x2) && (x1<=x3)) || ((x1>x2) && (x1>x3))` (`>` is the logical negation of `<=` here which will make this work despite the above).

Let's call `(x1>x2) = z1` and `(x1>x3) = z2`. Then this can be [simplified](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x1+%26%26+x2)+%7C%7C+(!x1+%26%26+!x2)) to: `(!z1 || z2) && (z1 || !z2)` (i used the names A and B in the link).

- Introduce two new binary-variables `z1, z2`
- Use a bigM-based formulation [like this page 4](http://scip.zib.de/workshop/scip_lodi.pdf) to create an indicator for your relation:

  - `x1 <= x2 + M * z1` where M is a big constant; `(z1=0) -> x1 <= x2`
  - `x1 <= x3 + M * z2` where M is another big constant; `(z2=0) -> x1 <= x3`
- Now we need the above: `(!z1 || z2) && (z1 || !z2)`

  - This is basically a `!(z1 xor z2)`, here `1-(z1 xor z2)` (look at the truth-table in the "simplified" link above ) and you can follow a very active Stackoverflow-user [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.de/2016/02/xor-as-linear-inequalities.html) to linearize the `xor`:

    - Introduce another binary-variable `z3`
    - Add linear constraints

      - `z3 <= (1-z1) + (1-z2)`
      - `z3 >= (1-z1) - (1-z2)`
      - `z3 >= (1-z2) - (1-z1)`
      - `z3 <= 2 - (1-z1) - (1-z2)`
  - `z3` is now `z1 xor z2`
  - Add constraint: `z3 == 0`

(There might be some error in the above, but the concept should be ok. With code at hands you should be able to make it work)

Comment: This is awesome! So we know that z3 = !(z1 XOR z2). What's the difference (1) introducing z3 and the additional constraints to linearize XOR, and (2) just adding the constraint that z1 == z2?